# Connect to a remote ODBC database

Tags: sql, excel, vba, odbc

I have an application that runs and get data in realtime, and there are two workstations doing same job in order to have a backup of data if one of them fails. Since every workstation can acquire data under its own parameters, sometimes data is not the same. I want to analyze both databases and compare them.  I use this code code in a vba excel macro in order to get data from an ODBC database, but I can run it just in the local computer.

Could you give me some advice in order to access to the database from another computer? The two workstations are in the same network, so I need to get the data with a code that use the IP address from the other workstation.

```
Sconnect = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Insite;UID=;Pwd=;"
sSQLString = "SELECT * FROM ADBI.ListOfRuns WHERE WellID=strWell"

Conn.Open Sconnect
mrs.Open sSQLString, Sconnect
```

Comment: Do you have DSNs for both of them? If so, just change the DSN in the connection string.

Comment: Have you verified the connection string? http://www.dofactory.com/reference/connection-strings

Comment: Guys, that is the problem, I don't know how to get the DNS. I have tried to open the connection to the ODBC, but i don't know the parameters or inputs in order to get there.  I have tried using the Data Sources (ODBC) in Windows, but I am affraid my knowledge is not enough.  I am sure that I can access the database with that code (including the connection string), but only from the local workstation, my issue is related to get the remote machine.

Comment: You might also be interested in this [link] https://www.dmxzone.com/go/312/how-to-generate-an-ado-connection-string/